# Unable to install mysqlclient for mac on mojave

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I am using Python + Django + MySql in my web application. 
Whenever I tried to install mysqlclient I getting mutliple errors.

Now I am stuck on this:

when I ran 
`pip install mysqlclient` I am getting following error:

[image]

[image]

Error Text Logs : https://pastebin.com/VrTGgpnr

Comment: Remove the images and post the text here.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps, please skip **step 1** and **step 2** if brew and MySQL are already installed in your system:

#### Step One: Install Brew

You need to install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) in you local machine. You can do it by:

```sh
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

#### Step Twp: Install MySQL

Using **Homebrew** you can install **mysql** simply by:

```sh
brew install mysql
```

Then setup the credentials in MySQL server using the following command:

```sh
mysql_secure_installation
```

Finally if you want to start at login and as a background service, run this:

```sh
brew services start mysql
```

Else

```sh
mysql.server start
```

#### Step Three: Install MySQL-Connector-C

For connecting any other application to MySQL, you need to install a connector. You can do it like this:

```sh
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

Then according to [mysqlclient's](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) documentation, you need to put a bugfix at `mysql_config`. For that first type `mysql_config` in terminal.:

```sh
>> mysql_config
Usage: /usr/local/bin/mysql_config [OPTIONS]
Compiler: ...
```

It will show where you need to find `mysql_config`. Then you can use any of the editor of your liking and change the following lines inside the `mysql_config`:

Change

```sh
# on macOS, on or about line 112:
# Create options
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -l "
```

To

```sh
# Create options
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
```

#### Step Four: Install XCode-Select

You can do this by:

```sh
xcode-select --install
```

#### Step Five: Install OpenSSL

Please run the following command:

```sh
brew install openssl
```

Then add its path to environment using following line:

```sh
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/
```

#### Step Six: Unlink MySQL and Link MySQL-Connector-C

You need to unlink **mysql** and link **mysql-connector-c**:

```sh
brew unlink mysql
brew link --overwrite mysql-connector-c
```

#### Step Seven: Install MySQLClient

You should be able to use `pip install mysqlclient` without any errors.

#### Step Eight: Link MySQL back again

Now, you need to do the opposit of **Step Six**:

```sh
brew unlink mysql-connector-c
brew link --overwrite mysql
```

Hopefully now `mysqlclient` should work fine and will have no problem connecting your application from mysql to django.

FYI, I have written the very much same thing in [this blog post](https://ruddra.com/posts/install-mysqlclient-macos/) as well.

Comment: At first lots of newbies might be thinking about this solution is too long but trust me this is the Almighty formulae in solving mysqlclient issues with python Django

Answer (score -1):

You can use the official MySQL Connector/Python.

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

You don't need to install OpenSSL or any other library.

More details about installation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-python/8.0/installation.html

Here's how to configure your app: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html